# Determine if BST is valid: failing some test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am trying to find a solution for LeetCode problem [98. Validate Binary Search Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree, *determine if it is a valid binary search tree (BST).*
>
> A **valid BST** is defined as follows:
>
> - The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys **less than** the node's key.
> - The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys **greater than** the node's key.
> - Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.

Following is the code that is already provided:

```
class TreeNode(object):
     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right

class Solution(object):
    def isValidBST(self, root):
        # your code
```

Following is my implementation:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isValidBST(self, root):
        if not root:
            return []
        if self.isValidBST(root.left)< [root.val] < self.isValidBST(root.right):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

### Problem

The code passes a few test cases (like `root = [5,1,4,null,null,3,6]`), but also fails a few. For example, it fails the following test:

- Input: `root = [2,1,3]`, which represents this tree:

  ```
      2
     / \
    1   3
  ```
- Expected output: True

My code returns False.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with this implementation is that `isValidBST` is supposed to return a boolean, so the following pieces of code don't make sense:

- `return []`: that should be `return True`
- `self.isValidBST(root.left)< [root.val]`: this would be comparing a boolean with a list, which is not supported (nor does it have a meaning). Even if you expected the function to return a list here, that list would be empty (as you only return `[]` as a list -- see previous point).

A way to make it work is to pass extra (optional) arguments to `isValidBST` that provide a "window" (range) for the values of the given tree: all its nodes should have values within that window or it is not a BST. Initially that window can be set with default values to -Infinity to Infinity.

Here is a spoiler in case you cannot make it work:

> `class Solution(object):
>      def isValidBST(self, root, low=float('-inf'), high=float('inf')):
>          return (not root or
>                  low < root.val < high and self.isValidBST(root.left, low, root.val)
>                                        and self.isValidBST(root.right, root.val, high))`

Alternatively you could make a helper function that does not return a boolean, but returns the window (range) that a given subtree actually spans (so its minimum and maximum values). If either span retrieved from the two subtrees violates the current root node's value, it is not a BST. But it is important to see that this function must be a *different* function from the main function, since the main function must return a boolean.

Yet another alternative is to perform an inorder traversal. Each visited value must be greater than the previously visited value.

Comment: Thank you it's working now.. Can you tell me why we haven't assigned low and high to 0?

Comment: If you set low and high to 0, you are saying that any value outside the window (0, 0) makes the BST invalid, which obviously is not true.  In the beginning of the traversal there is no limitation to the value that the root can have, so we should start with (-inf, inf).